# Probability of getting a head on multiple tosses of a coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The probability of getting a head is 1/2 and so it is for tail. When you toss a coin once, the probability of not getting a head (which is the same as getting a tail) is 1/2. Now the probability of not getting a head on the second toss too is 1/2. So the probability of getting a head at the third toss should be:
Probability of not getting a head at the first toss * Probability of not getting a head at the second toss * Probability of getting a head at the third toss = (1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2) = 0.125.

0.125 is less than 0.5, which is the probability of getting a head. Now, thinking intuitively and not mathematically, shouldn't the probability of getting a head (or a tail) keep on increasing as I do more and more tosses? That is, if I do not get a head at the first toss, probability of getting it at the first toss should be greater and so on. Could anyone please clarify what I am thinking wrong?

Comment: Why it should increase? The throws are independent!

Comment: Your calculation resulting in $0.125$ is for the probability that the *first* head is on the third toss.

Comment: The probability of getting **at least** one head in the first $n$ tosses is $1$ minus the probability of only getting tails in the first $n$ tosses, hence equals $1-0.5^n$. Note that it increases. Does this satisfy your intuition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make it simple: two tosses. The probability of getting an head on the first toss is $0.5$, the probability of getting an head on the second toss is $0.5$. the probability of getting at least one head in two tosses is bigger than $0.5$.
You can do it counting the outcomes: HH, HT, TH, TT where H stands for head and T stands for tail. There are $3$ outcomes with an head out of all the $4$ possible outcomes. So the probability of getting **at least** one head increses and for two tosses is $3/4=0.75$.
Now try to generalize this to $3$ and to $n$ tosses if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are calculating is; the probability of getting three tails in three tosses $=0.125$

The probability of getting a head or a tail always remains $0.5$, no matter how many times you throw the coin.